# Select substring of text from span and compare with number

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I have the following html

```
<div _something="">
    <div _something="" class="class12928">
        <span _something="" class="ux-u-font-bold">Search results</span>
    </div>
    <div _something="" class="class12928">
        <span _something="" class="ux-u-font-light">329 item(s) found</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The number 329 is generated through a rest call and initially is 0 so the initial load shows the following:

```
<span _something="" class="ux-u-font-light">0 item(s) found</span>
```

I want to check if the rest calls are returning a number higher than 0 through xpath.

I got the span through the following xpath: //span[contains(text(),"item")]

I want to search for any number of items over 0

Comment: if your text part is constant `item(s) found` then simply get the text of required span and replace `item(s) found` with `''` and then parse the remaining string part to get the number.

Comment: I think the point is making parse operations after the rest call end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath,

to select the div element containing a span element which respect your condition (remove the last part `/parent::div` if you just want the `span`) :

```
//span[contains(.,"found")][substring-before(.," item(s)")>0]/parent::div
```

to check if the span elements contains a number higher than 0 (returns TRUE/FALSE) :

```
substring-before(//span[contains(.,"found")]," item(s)")>0
```

Comment: The first worked:  `//span[contains(.,"found")][substring-before(.," item(s)")>0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
//span [@class = 'ux-u-font-light' and contains(., 'item(s) found') and not (starts-with(., '0')) ]
```

Comment: This worked even the shorter version: `//span[contains(., 'item(s) found') and not (starts-with(., '0')) ]`